# Swing UI Frame was found stuck and shows grey screen in java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager

I am having problem like in some time when i run my application it shows grey screen instead showing proper UI and application keep on throws below exception. could you please any one give me the solution to fix this problem.

```
  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
     at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonUI.getMinimumSize(Unknown Source)
     at javax.swing.JComponent.getMinimumSize(Unknown Source)
     at java.awt.BorderLayout.minimumLayoutSize(Unknown Source)
     at java.awt.Container.minimumSize(Unknown Source)
     at java.awt.Container.getMinimumSize(Unknown Source)
     at javax.swing.JComponent.getMinimumSize(Unknown Source)
     at java.awt.FlowLayout.minimumLayoutSize(Unknown Source)
     at java.awt.Container.minimumSize(Unknown Source)
     at java.awt.Container.getMinimumSize(Unknown Source)
     at javax.swing.JComponent.getMinimumSize(Unknown Source)
     at java.awt.GridBagLayout.GetLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
     at java.awt.GridBagLayout.getLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
     at java.awt.GridBagLayout.ArrangeGrid(Unknown Source)
     at java.awt.GridBagLayout.arrangeGrid(Unknown Source)
     at java.awt.GridBagLayout.layoutContainer(Unknown Source)
     at java.awt.Container.layout(Unknown Source)
     at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Unknown Source)
     at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
     at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
     at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
     at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
     at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
     at java.awt.Container.validate(Unknown Source)
     at javax.swing.RepaintManager.validateInvalidComponents(Unknown Source)
     at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
     at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
     at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: `1)` Welcome on this forum, `2)` read [Frequently Asked Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), `3)` for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) with only one `JButton` generated this exception

Comment: Impossible to answer your question without seeing your code. My guess would be that you are manipulating Swing elements outside the EDT. Remember that Swing is not Thread-safe, and so everything related to Swing should be done in the EDT. SwingUtilities.invokeLater/invokeAndWait can help your for that.

Comment: It says java.lang.NullPointerException. Show us the code and the line where the exception is thrown.

Comment: @Averroes The source code where the NPE occurs is public: javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonUI.getMinimumSize. The line number is not available here.

Comment: I am using SwingUtilities.invokeLater() method in my code without checking whether the thread is EventQueue.isDispatchThread() or not. is it create any problem. please find below code.
    public void update(Runnable runnable)
    {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
    could you please suggest me right way?

Comment: @user1280096 you can use invokeLater on the EDT, it is not a problem. Unfortunately, we can't help you much more without seeing some code and most likely, only an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) will allow us to answer your question.

Comment: @user1280096 which part of SSCCE you don't understand, please about whats are the comments here, are you joking, or you have got some issue with this forum, sorry as you see battery not included in our magic globes with eyes that can see code in your PC,

Answer (score 0):

Remove the components in your screen one by one till the problem goes. With the information in your qn nothing more can be said.

Comment: The exception shows only that much and didn't the place of the code where exception occurred. also we were used more component and it's very big application. we can't go ahead with removing one by one. Also i feel the issue may be due to below code.

public void update(Runnable runnable)
   {
           SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable);
   }
Note: this is the code which takes care of updating UI.